# systemd not playing a sound

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd unit which execute a script that is supposed to play a sound in case a certain event happens i.e. it contains a line

```
mplayer /home/myusername/Music/audiofile.WAV
```

This does not happen. The script looks correct, since it works when run on its own.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: Does the script get executed and no sound is played or is it possible that no sound is played because the script is not executed?

Comment: The script is executed, as systemctl status shows. The problem is solved by adding a couple of lines in the systemd unit, which I include in the next answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the systemd unit is not run by the user as default.
In the systemd unit, under the section service, add the following two lines

```
User=<yourusername>
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
```

and the unit should work.

Answer (score 0):

Running Debian 11 in a Raspberry Pi, it was enough for me to add this to the service unit file:

```
Environment="PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH=/run/user/1000/pulse/"
```

Keep in mind here 1000 is the user id used to run the service, so change it accordingly to your setup

*Source*: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379890/how-to-play-a-sound-from-a-systemd-service-on-ubuntu